# Restar Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Necesito restar los resultados de **bodegasTotales** - **ventasTotales** La idea es realizar la resta cuando coincida el concepto.

```
    const bodegasTotales = {}
          bodegaFiltrada.map(item => {
            if (item.lista) {
              item.lista.map(concepto => {
                if (concepto.producto) {
                  const productoNombre = concepto.producto
                  if (!bodegasTotales[productoNombre]) {
                    bodegasTotales[productoNombre] = { unidades: 0, peso: 0 }
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.unidades) {
                    bodegasTotales[productoNombre].unidades += parseInt(
                      concepto.unidades
                    )
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.peso) {
                    bodegasTotales[productoNombre].peso += parseInt(
                      concepto.peso
                    )
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          })
     const ventasTotales = {}
          
          ventasFiltradas.map(item => {
            if (item.lista) {
              item.lista.map(concepto => {
                if (concepto.producto) {
                  const productoNombre = concepto.producto
                  if (!ventasTotales[productoNombre]) {
                    ventasTotales[productoNombre] = { unidades: 0, peso: 0 }
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.unidades) {
                    ventasTotales[productoNombre].unidades += parseInt(
                      concepto.unidades
                    )
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.peso) {
                    ventasTotales[productoNombre].peso += parseInt(
                      concepto.peso
                    )
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          })
```

Estoy tratando con algo como esto pero no me funciona. He probado reduce, pero no se como se debe implementar para que funcione cuando coincida el concepto.

```
      const resultado = {}
          
          bodegaFiltrada.map(item => {
            if (item.lista) {
              item.lista.map(concepto => {
                if (concepto.producto) {
                  const productoNombre = concepto.producto
                  if (!resultado[productoNombre]) {
                    resultado[productoNombre] = { unidades: 0, peso: 0 }
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.unidades) {
                    bodegasTotales[productoNombre].unidades -= parseInt(
                      concepto.unidades
                    )
                  }
                  
                  if (concepto.peso) {
                    bodegasTotales[productoNombre].peso -= parseInt(
                      concepto.peso
                    )
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          })
```

Comment: Todo el código va como texto por favor

Comment: Lo tenía pero no me permite guardar si lo copio todo

Comment: Por que tu pregunta es mayomente código, debes agregarlo como texto y a la par explicar de forma funcional que hace y que no el código

Comment: Gracias, ya he quitado las imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que tenes un array de objetos pero no detecte todas sus claves asi que te arme este ejemplo donde te arme dos colecciones una del stock total de los productos y otro de las ventas , podes combinar   `map` , para crear un nuevo array filtrado , como lo intentaste hacer y tambien barrer con un `forEach` el otro arreglo que seria el de las ventas, separe lo mas posible las variables para que sea mas entendible el codigo
, faltarian unas validaciones pero en principio te sirviria

```js
const bodegasTotales = [
    {
        producto: 'vino',
        precio: 100,
        unidades: 10,
    },
    {
        producto: 'cerveza',
        precio: 100,
        unidades: 20,
    }
];

const ventasTotales = [
    {
        producto: 'vino',
        precio: 100,
        unidades: 1,
    },
    {
        producto: 'cerveza',
        precio: 100,
        unidades: 3,
    },
];


const stockActual = bodegasTotales.map(bodega=>{
    let CantidadVendida = 0
    let cantidadActual = bodega.unidades
     
     ventasTotales.forEach(venta=> {
        if(venta.producto == bodega.producto)
        CantidadVendida = venta.unidades
        
    })
     
    bodega.unidades = cantidadActual- CantidadVendida

  return bodega

 
})
console.log(stockActual);
```